# Mercurial deny clone exact branch in repository

Tags: mercurial, branch, acl, hgrc

I'm using http to serve two branches in HG.

I need one user to have access only for certain branch.

How can I deny cloning exact branch with AclExtension?

My .hg/hgrc is

```
pretxnchangegroup = python:hgext.acl.hook

[acl]
sources = http, pull, push

[acl.allow]
* = admin #admin has full access
release = baduser #baduser has access only to release branch

[acl.deny.branches]
default = baduser #deny this branch for user baduser
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: What authentication mechanism do you use through HTTP ? What I mean by that is, how do you determine the user that is currently connected ?

Comment: @krtek, i use htpasswd file, simple apache auth